# ExtJS 4.1 treepanel - expanding a treepanel is resulting in duplicate records

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJS 4.1. I have a TreePanel which I bind to one of two TreeStore. After I rebind a store & expand collapse nodes, records are getting duplicate & I see error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined`

Another issue is, I am only able to bind store once. When i call treePanel.setRootNode() second time it does not work (irrespective of whether I expand the nodes or not).

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Ef/98/)

Here is the code:

```
var sportsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  root: {
    expanded: true,
    id: 133,
    children: [{
        text: "Audi",
        id: 1,
        leaf: true
      },
      {
        text: "sports cars",
        expanded: true,
        id: 2,
        children: [{
            id: 3,
            text: "Porsche",
            leaf: true
          },
          {
            text: "Mustang",
            id: 4,
            leaf: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Jaguar",
        id: 5,
        leaf: true
      }
    ]
  }
});


var carStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  root: {
    expanded: true,
    id: 1444,
    children: [{
        id: 6,
        text: "Toyota",
        leaf: true
      },
      {
        text: "cars",
        id: 7,
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            id: 8,
            text: "honda",
            leaf: true
          },
          {
            text: "Nissan",
            id: 9,
            leaf: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Kia",
        id: 10,
        leaf: true
      }
    ]
  }
});



Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  title: 'Car Simple Tree',
  width: 300,
  height: 450,

  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

  items: [{
      xtype: 'button',
      text: 'sports',
      handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the sports button!');
        var t = Ext.getCmp('tp');

        t.setRootNode(sportsStore.getRootNode());
      }
    },

    {
      xtype: 'button',
      text: 'car',
      handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the car button!');
        var t = Ext.getCmp('tp');

        t.setRootNode(carStore.getRootNode());
      }
    },
    {

      xtype: 'treepanel',
      id: 'tp',
      store: sportsStore,
      rootVisible: false,
      lines: true
    }
  ]


});
```

Comment: Check that  **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2jl9)** this will help you.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav: You are not using store in this case. when we use store, we run into this issue.

Comment: @SharpCoder ware you able to see if the answer I had bellow helps?

Comment: @Akrion: it is working. But its a hacky way to achieve the desired result. Let's see if we get more answers in next two days (which I doubt).

Comment: @SharpCoder hey no rush. Just was wondering if you have a chance to see it and  your opinion on the result. As I said `it might not be your cup of tea` :). Earlier version of Sencha as far as I remember had plenty of stuff like these where hacks ware pretty much required. I would love to see an actual solution without re-create as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record you know your problem is solved in one line in 6.0 with just calling `setStore()` and passing as parameter the store you want right?

[Here is a demo of this working in 6.0](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kd2).

I played with this for a good amount of time and although my Sencha is somewhat rusty (used to be a big fan back in the day) I managed to get something working.

Now it might not be your cup of tea but it does exactly what you want ... you change the stores and expanding/collapsing works etc. The `trick` is I dynamically re-create the tree on every store change and set the store as the default store to that new tree. The `decommissioned` trees are removed by `Ext.destroy` etc.

[Here is that Ext 4.1 working example in Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kd3)

And here is the code for your reference:

```
Ext.define('Thing', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int'
  }, {
    name: 'text',
    type: 'string'
  }]
});

var sportsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  model: 'Thing',
  storeId: 'sportsStore',
  clearOnLoad: true,
  root: {
    expanded: true,
    id: 133,
    children: [{
      text: "Audi",
      id: 1,
      leaf: true
    }, {
      text: "sports cars",
      expanded: true,
      id: 2,
      children: [{
        id: 3,
        text: "Porsche",
        leaf: true
      }, {
        text: "Mustang",
        id: 4,
        leaf: true
      }]
    }, {
      text: "Jaguar",
      id: 5,
      leaf: true
    }]
  }
});
var carStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  model: 'Thing',
  storeId: 'carStore',
  clearOnLoad: true,
  root: {
    expanded: true,
    id: 1444,
    children: [{
      id: 6,
      text: "Toyota",
      leaf: true
    }, {
      text: "cars",
      id: 7,
      expanded: true,
      children: [{
        id: 8,
        text: "honda",
        leaf: true
      }, {
        text: "Nissan",
        id: 9,
        leaf: true
      }]
    }, {
      text: "Kia",
      id: 10,
      leaf: true
    }]
  }
});
// This function does the magic by removing/then destroying the old tree and 
// adding the newly created one with default new store setup
function setupTree(storeName) {
  var pnl = Ext.getCmp('pnl');
  var treePanel = Ext.getCmp('tp')
  if (treePanel) {
    pnl.remove(treePanel)
    Ext.destroy(treePanel)
  }
  pnl.add(new Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'tp',
    autoRender: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: storeName,
    animate: false,
    lines: true
  }))
}

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  id: 'pnl',
  title: 'Car Simple Tree',
  width: 300,
  height: 450,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody('#canvas'),
  items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'sports',
    handler: function() {
      setupTree('sportsStore')
    }
  }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'car',
    handler: function() {
      setupTree('carStore')
    }
  }],
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(self) {
      setupTree('sportsStore')
    }
  }
});
```

I also added `ids` to the stored as well as defined a `model` for the stores just to be more close to `best practices` etc.

The thing that makes this move is the `setupTree` function which looks for a tree with certain id, if it finds it `cleans it` and then creates a new one with a default store the one we clicked on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach, which may be a workaround, but ExtJS 4.1 version has some issues in `UpdateIndexes()` method:

- define an empty tree store (`baseStore`) and bind it to the tree panel
- on every button click, fill this empty store with data from appropriate store.

Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        Ext.FocusManager.enable();

        // Stores
        var baseStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                leaf: false,
                children: []
            }
        });
        var sportsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
            expanded: true,
            id: 133,
            children: [
            {
                text: "Audi",
                id: 1,
                leaf: true
                },
                {
                text: "sports cars",
                expanded: true,
                id: 2,
                children: [{
                    id: 3,
                    text: "Porsche",
                    leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                    text: "Mustang",
                    id: 4,
                    leaf: true
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                text: "Jaguar",
                id: 5,
                leaf: true
                }
            ]
            }
        });
        var carStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
            expanded: true,
            id: 1444,
            children: [
                {
                id: 6,
                text: "Toyota",
                leaf: true
                },
                {
                text: "cars",
                id: 7,
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                    id: 8,
                    text: "honda",
                    leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                    text: "Nissan",
                    id: 9,
                    leaf: true
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                text: "Kia",
                id: 10,
                leaf: true
                }
            ]
            }
        });                 

        // Filling data
        function fillStore(xparent, xnode) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xnode.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var current = xnode.childNodes[i];
                var added = xparent.appendChild(
                    {
                    text: current.data.text,
                    leaf: current.data.leaf,
                    id: current.data.id
                    }
                );
                if (current.data.leaf === false) {
                    fillStore(added, current);
                }
            }
        }
        function setStore(store) {
            var root = baseStore.getRootNode();

            if (root.hasChildNodes()) {
                root.removeAll();
            }
            fillStore(root, store.getRootNode());
        }

        // First fill
        setStore(carStore);

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Car Simple Tree',
        width: 300,
        height: 450,

        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        items: [
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'sports',
            handler: function() {
                alert('You clicked the sports button!');
                var t = Ext.getCmp('tp');

                setStore(sportsStore);
            }
            },
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'car',
            handler: function() {
                alert('You clicked the car button!');
                var t = Ext.getCmp('tp');

                setStore(carStore);
                }
            },
            {
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            id: 'tp',
            store: baseStore,
            rootVisible: false,
            lines: true
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Notes:

Working fiddle can be found [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kcm).

Comment: This is great. Only issue is, the model that I bind to my store has 15+ properties. and in some cases I have close to 300 nodes. In my case `fillStore()` will get long. I also need to evaluate the performance.